# Rx.net implement retry functionality on disconnect/error in observable

Tags: c#, .net, observable, system.reactive, rx.net

Below is the following code:

```
    public class FooService
    {
        private ITransportService _transportService;
        public FooService(ITransportService transportService)
        {
            _transportService = transportService;
            _transportService.Connect();
        }

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<FooData> observer)
        {
            return _transportService.GetObservable()
                .Subscribe(observer);
        }
    }

    public interface ITransportService
    {
        ConnectionState State { get; }
        bool Connect();
        IObservable<FooData> GetObservable();
    }

    public class ClientConsumingProgram
    {
        class FooObserver : IObserver<FooData>
        {
            public void OnNext(FooData value)
            {
                //Client consuming without interruption
            }
            //.. on error.. onCompleted
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            var fooService = new FooService(transportService);
            var fooObserver = new FooObserver();
            var disposable = fooService.Subscribe(fooObserver);
        }
    }
```

I want to implement following:

When transport service is disconnected (socket closed from server), I want application to retry for few times, but foo service first needs to call `Connect` on `_transportService` and then once `State` is connected, call GetObservable.

Desired result is `OnNext` on `FooObserver` keeps on ticking on client side, if `_transportService` is connect again before max retry, and once it's exceeds max error OnError should be fired.

Can someone point me to the right direction for implementing this?

---

UPDATE

```
public class FooService
{
    private ITransportService _transportService;
    public FooService(ITransportService transportService)
    {
        _transportService = transportService;
        _transportService.Connect();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<FooData> observer)
    {
        return _transportService.GetConnectionStateObservable()
        .Select(cs => cs == ConnectionState.Open)
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Select(isOpen => isOpen
            ? _transportService.GetObservable()   //if open, return observable
            : Observable.Start(() => _transportService.Connect()) //if not open, call connect and wait for connection to open
                .IgnoreElements()
                .Select(_ => default(FooData))
                .Concat(Observable.Never<FooData>())
        )
        .Switch()
        .Subscribe(observer);
    }
}

public interface ITransportService
{
    IObservable<ConnectionState> GetConnectionStateObservable();
    bool Connect();
    IObservable<FooData> GetObservable();
}

public class FooData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }
}

public enum ConnectionState
{
    Open,
    Close
}

public class FooMockTransportService : ITransportService
{
    public ConnectionState State { get; set; }
    private BehaviorSubject<ConnectionState> _connectionSubject = new BehaviorSubject<ConnectionState>(ConnectionState.Close);
    private bool _shouldDisconnect;

    public FooMockTransportService()
    {
        _shouldDisconnect = true;
    }

    public bool Connect()
    {
        State = ConnectionState.Open;
        _connectionSubject.OnNext(ConnectionState.Open);
        return true;
    }

    public IObservable<ConnectionState> GetConnectionStateObservable()
    {
        return _connectionSubject.AsObservable();
    }

    public IObservable<FooData> GetObservable()
    {
        return Observable.Create<FooData>(
            o=>
            {
                TaskPoolScheduler.Default.Schedule(() =>
                {
                    o.OnNext(new FooData { Id = 1, Msg = "First" });
                    o.OnNext(new FooData { Id = 2, Msg = "Sec" });

                    //Simulate disconnection, ony once
                    if(_shouldDisconnect)
                    {
                        _shouldDisconnect = false;
                        State = ConnectionState.Close;
                        o.OnError(new Exception("Disconnected"));
                        _connectionSubject.OnNext(ConnectionState.Close);
                    }

                    o.OnNext(new FooData { Id = 3, Msg = "Third" });
                    o.OnNext(new FooData { Id = 4, Msg = "Fourth" });
                });
                return () => { };
            });
    }
}

public class Program
{
    class FooObserver : IObserver<FooData>
    {
        public void OnCompleted()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnError(Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }

        public void OnNext(FooData value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value.Id);
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        var transportService = new FooMockTransportService();
        var fooService = new FooService(transportService);
        var fooObserver = new FooObserver();
        var disposable = fooService.Subscribe(fooObserver);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Code is compliable and also contains suggestions for Shlomo.
Current output:

```
1
2
System.Exception: Disconnected
```

Desired output, on disconnect it should catch and retry every 1 sec as an example to see whether it's connected or not:

```
1
2
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly.  You can create fully resiliant services with it, and it was designed for this problem.

Comment: I knew about polly and using it for REST, but here it would be great, if i get the pure RX solution, i have simplified the code here, but actual code has more nuances

Comment: You can look at Observable Defer and DelaySubscription

Comment: @MKMohanty - Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Enigmativity sure

Comment: @ThomasBecker - Please don't edit questions to invalidate answers. I think I've fixed your edit to show the new code while leaving the original intact. Please confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you control `ITransportService`, I would recommend adding a property:

```
public interface ITransportService
{
    ConnectionState State { get; }
    bool Connect();
    IObservable<FooData> GetObservable();
    IObservable<ConnectionState> GetConnectionStateObservable();
}
```

Once you can get the states in an observable fashion, producing the observable becomes easier:

```
public class FooService
{
    private ITransportService _transportService;
    public FooService(ITransportService transportService)
    {
        _transportService = transportService;
        _transportService.Connect();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<FooData> observer)
    {
        return _transportService.GetConnectionStateObservable()
            .Select(cs => cs == ConnectionState.Open)
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Select(isOpen => isOpen 
                ? _transportService.GetObservable()   //if open, return observable
                : Observable.Start(() => _transportService.Connect()) //if not open, call connect and wait for connection to open
                    .IgnoreElements()
                    .Select(_ => default(FooData))
                    .Concat(Observable.Never<FooData>())
            )
            .Switch()
            .Subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

If you don't control `ITransportService`, I would recommend creating an interface that inherits from it where you can add a similar property.

As an aside, I would recommend you ditch `FooObserver`, you almost never need to fashion your own observer. Expose the observable, and calling a `Subscribe` overload on the Observable normally does the trick.

I can't test any of this though: there's no clarity as to what the retry logic should be like, what the return value for `Connect` means, or what the `ConnectionState` class is, and the code doesn't compile. You should try to fashion your question as a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

---

**UPDATE**:

The following handles the test code as expected:

```
public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<FooData> observer)
{
    return _transportService.GetConnectionStateObservable()
        .Select(cs => cs == ConnectionState.Open)
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Select(isOpen => isOpen
            ? _transportService.GetObservable()   //if open, return observable
                .Catch(Observable.Never<FooData>())
            : Observable.Start(() => _transportService.Connect()) //if not open, call connect and wait for connection to open
                .IgnoreElements()
                .Select(_ => default(FooData))
                .Concat(Observable.Never<FooData>())
        )
        .Switch()
        .Subscribe(observer);
}
```

Only change from the original posted code is the additional `.Catch(Observable.Never<FooData>())`. As written, this code will run forever. I hope you have some way to terminate the observable external to what's posted.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking time for answering, I have update the code which is compiled, what I really want is to handle disconnection in ongoing stream, and retry the connect, once connect returns true, that means server is up, and it can stream again. let me know if any more clarification needed

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: yes that solves it.. I had to make GetConnectionStateObservable listen to the heartbeat, this example is best use case of using Observable.Never.. thanks for it.. much to learn :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot write Rx code that effectively executes like this:

```
o.OnNext(new FooData { Id = 1, Msg = "First" });
o.OnNext(new FooData { Id = 2, Msg = "Sec" });

o.OnError(new Exception("Disconnected"));

o.OnNext(new FooData { Id = 3, Msg = "Third" });
o.OnNext(new FooData { Id = 4, Msg = "Fourth" });
```

The contract for an observable is a stream of zero or more values that ends with either an error or a complete signal. They cannot emit further values.

Now, I appreciate that this code might be for testing purposes, but if you create an impossible stream you'll end up writing impossible code.

The correct approach is to use `.Switch()`, as per Shlomo's answer. If there's some delay in connection then the `GetConnectionStateObservable` should only return a value when it is connected. Shlomo's answer remains correct.

Comment: rx code is just for simulation, creating disconnection only once.. apologies if it had introduced confusion. thanks for explaining further to shlomo's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating my comment:

As Shlomo already shown in his answer how you can take advantage of connection state observable, what I guess you want is to subscribe it again when disconnect happen.

For that use Observable.Defer

```
return Observable.Defer(() => your final observable)
```

and now on disconnect if you want to subscribe again use Retry

```
return Observable.Defer(() => your final observable).Retry(3)
```

but you might need to delay your retries, either linearly or with exponential back-off
strategy, for this use DelaySubscription

```
return Observable.Defer(() => your_final_observable.DelaySubscription(strategy)).Retry(3)
```

here's the final code, with retry every second:

```
        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<FooData> observer)
        {
            return Observable.Defer(() => {
                return _transportService.GetConnectionStateObservable()
            .Select(cs => cs == ConnectionState.Open)
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Select(isOpen => isOpen
                ? _transportService.GetObservable()   //if open, return observable
                : Observable.Start(() => _transportService.Connect()) //if not open, call connect and wait for connection to open
                    .IgnoreElements()
                    .Select(_ => default(FooData))
                    .Concat(Observable.Never<FooData>())
            )
            .Switch().DelaySubscription(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            })
            .Retry(2)
            .Subscribe(observer);
        }
```

*Some caveats to remember*:

This DelaySubscription will delay first call also, so if it's a problem, create a count variable and only when count > 0 use DelaySubscription else use normal observable.